# Unwanted changing of bool and persisting it in storage | Flutter

Tags: flutter, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am using **ListView.builder** to create list of **Card**'s.

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
     return ListTile(
        title: MyCard(
          cardId: index,
),);},);
```

In **MyCard** class i persist boolean **`shouldRemind`** in storage by using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin.

```
class MyCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCard({
    super.key,
    required this.cardId,
  });

  @override
  State<MyCard> createState() => _CardState();
  final int cardId;
}

class _CardState extends State<MyCard> {
  bool shouldRemind = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      shouldRemind = prefs.getBool('boolSwitcherKey') ?? false;
    });
  }

  saveBool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('boolSwitcherKey', shouldRemind);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: shouldRemind
          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 0, 0)
          : const Color.fromRGBO(32, 32, 32, 1),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 180,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (shouldRemind == true) {
                        shouldRemind = false;
                      } else {
                        shouldRemind = true;
                      }
                      saveBool();
                    });
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.alarm),
                  label: const Text("prr prr")),
              Text(shouldRemind.toString())
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Problem is bool **`shouldRemind`**, after it is changed by clicking button, it is only one of it, so every single copy of **MyCard** getting value equal to that what i changed before, i think that is the reason it look like this :
[video](https://streamable.com/njrkc0)

I want to have unique bool to every widget, so that after rendering my user another Card value of bool won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with

```
 await prefs.setBool('boolSwitcherKey', shouldRemind);
```

you overwrite the same boolean every single time. You could use the index of the current element or the id of your card to create a unique key.

```
await prefs.setBool('boolSwitcherKey' + widget.cardId, shouldRemind);
```

and the same to get the bool

```
shouldRemind = prefs.getBool('boolSwitcherKey' + widget.cardId) ?? false;
```

Answer (score 1):

While every card have `cardId`, you can use it to save and retrieve from `SharedPreferences`

`'${widget.cardId} boolSwitcherKey'`

```dart
loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      shouldRemind = prefs.getBool('${widget.cardId} boolSwitcherKey') ?? false;
    });
  }

  saveBool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('${widget.cardId} boolSwitcherKey', shouldRemind);
  }
```